# How to parse my logs in Symfony2 (Monolog\Logger)

Tags: symfony, logging, monolog, log-level

I use Monolog\Logger in a service like this :

```
<service id="my_service" class="Acme\DemoBundle\Service\MyService">
    <tag name="monolog.logger" channel="mychannel" />
    <argument type="service" id="logger" />
    <argument type="service" ... />
</service>
```

In the service :

```
use Monolog\Logger;
class MyService{

private $logger;


public function __construct(Logger $logger, ...) {
    $this->logger = $logger;
    ...
}

}
```

I want to use the same channel that my service in my Controller so, in my controller, I have :

```
private function getLogger() {
    return $this->get('monolog.logger.mychannel');
}
```

I would like to retrieve records by level of my logs.
How can I do this ?

Thanks you.

Comment: Do you need to parse logs? They are text files. Just take them and parse. Level is also there. You can grep for it if you like.

Answer (score 0):

I don't need to parse logs, I just want to know if there are errors or warnings.

I added this in my Controller :

```
private function hasLevelErrorHandler($type = "error") {
  $handlers = $this->getLoggger()->getHandlers();
  $records = $handlers[0]->getRecords();

  if( $type == "error" ) {
      $levels = array(Logger::ERROR, Logger::CRITICAL, Logger::ALERT,    Logger::EMERGENCY);
  } else {
      $levels = array(Logger::WARNING);
  }

  foreach( $records as $record ) {
      if( in_array($record['level'], $levels) ) {
          return true;
      }
  }
}
```

Is it a good way to do ?
Thanks.

**[EDIT]**
I don't have the same result with app.php and app_dev.php...

So, I don't know how can I parse my logs...
If you have ideas...

Thanks you.